# How can I set an image to have a transparent background in C# without using Bitmap.MakeTransparent()?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I want to set an image to have a transparent background, but I do not want to replace all pixels of a specific colour with transparency.

To be more specific, the image is a thumbnail image for a folder, obtained via IShellItemImageFactory.GetImage. This gives me a Bitmap, as displayed in Windows Explorer thumbnail view, but the background is solid white.

I can use Bitmap.MakeTransparent on it, and that will work in most cases, but in any cases where the thumbnail image contains white itself (for example, a folder that contains images, which include white colours).

Incidently, this is the first time in over 10 years as a developer that, after googling my question, I have not found an answer anywhere, and I've actually had to ask it myself. (I think that means I just levelled up! Yippee, I am now a level 2 developer...)

Comment: May be this can help you : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DrawTransparentImageUsingAB10102005010514AM/DrawTransparentImageUsingAB.aspx

Comment: Where do you want to display the images (like, a treeview, button...)? And what do you mean by *but in any cases where the thumbnail image contains white itself*?

Comment: I've written an image viewer application, and display the thumbnails in my usercontrol on a flowlayoutpanel. When the mouse moves over a thumbnail, I draw a gradient-filled background (different colours depending on selected or hottracked). The issue is, if a folder thumbnail image contains white somewhere inside it, that part will now (incorrectly) be transparent, and my thumbnail paint handler will paint that part of the image using the gradient (as expected, because the image "says" that part is transparent). I hope this is now clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flood-fill algorithm to fill pixels of the same color from the OUTSIDE as you need it.  It is something similar to magic wand in photoshop.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

What I would do is flood-fill with some obscure color (Magenta always does it for me), then replace that color with transparent (I don't know if flood filling with transparent pixels is feasible).

Comment: That's going to fail if the image has white pixels on its border. For example, take a look at the NBA logo: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/07/NBALogo.svg

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. I'll try it out and update if your answer is correct! (There are no white pixels on the border as far as I've seen. And if there are in rare cases, that will be no worse that Bitmap.MakeTransparent anyway.)

Comment: It won't fail if the image is clipped just to the edges of the red and blue areas, but I thing that OP doesn't have that kind of images anyway.

Answer (score 1):

So what you're getting from `IShellItemImageFactory.GetImage` is a composite image that contains the original image on a white background? I suspect the white background is there if the image doesn't have the same aspect ratio as the thumbnail size. For example, if you ask for a 96x96 thumbnail of a 640x480 image, there's going to be some white space at top and bottom.

If that's the case, you have a problem. You can't differentiate between white pixels that are contained in the image, and white pixels that are added by `GetImage`.

There are a few things you could do. You could load the image and resize it yourself. That's probably the easiest. You'd want to maintain your own thumbnail cache then.

Or you could examine the image returned by `GetImage` to look for white space on the sides. Basically, if every pixel on a row (or column) is white, then make that row (or column) transparent. It's a little more complicated than that ([the NBA logo](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/07/NBALogo.svg), for example). But that's essentially what you'd want to do.

Comment: Hmmm... I wish I could load the image and rescale it myself. That would be so much simpler! But this is a *folder* thumbnail. i.e. its generated by the shell. Also, I ask the shell for a 256-256 image; as far as I know that is the size maintained by the shell for thumbnails. Actually, I wonder if the flags I pass to GetImage are correct. The relevant line of code is: HResult hRes = ((IShellItemImageFactory)ppsi).GetImage(new SIZE(256, 256), SIIGBF.SIIGBF_BIGGERSIZEOK | SIIGBF.SIIGBF_RESIZETOFIT, out hbitmap);

Comment: @Jerome: Does it help to call the `MakeTransparent` overload that takes a color parameter? It's not clear to me if you're trying to eliminate the possible border in the 256x256 image, or if you're trying to eliminate (make transparent) some part of your own background. If you're trying to eliminate your own background, make the transparent part something hideous (like `Color.Lime`), and then call `MakeTransparent(Color.Lime)`.

Comment: Thanks, but solved with flood-fill. To answer your question though... I was trying to eliminate the white border around the actual shell thumbnail bitmap image (or black border if I fiddled with the flag parameters to the shell image extracting method). So even the MakeTransparent overload that accepts a colour would still have the same problem: it eliminates *all* white pixels from the image, creating transparent "holes" inside the image.